# How to get the unique values from magento custom table?

Tags: magento-1.9, database

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('saplocation/saplocation')->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('location', array('like' => '%'.$location.'%'));

foreach ($collection as $values) {
    array_push($returnjson, $values['pincode']);
}
echo json_encode($returnjson);
```

How to get the unique values from magento table, i have tried distinct but it is not working. please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$return = array();
$collection = Mage::getModel('saplocation/saplocation')->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('location', array('like' => '%'.$location.'%'));
foreach ($collection as $values) {
    $return[$values['pincode']] = $values['pincode'];
}
echo json_encode(array_values($return));
```

Comment: You are awesome Marius.

Answer (score 1):

```
        $returnjson = array();

        $collection = Mage::getModel('saplocation/saplocation')->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('location', array('like' => '%'.$location.'%'));
                    //->addFieldToFilter('location', $location);
        foreach ($collection as $values) {

            $returnjson[$values['pincode']] = $values['pincode'];
        }
        echo json_encode($returnjson);
```